# C++ multi dimensional array

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-dimensional array and pointers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367426/multi-dimensional-array-and-pointers-in-c)

Hi,
In 1D I can declare an array like,

```
int *image = new int[W*H];
```

But in 2D how can I declare an array?

```
int *image = new int[W][H]; -- is it wrong??
```

Comment: Nobody answered this correctly, here or at the duplicated question. I can't post my answer here, because this question is closed, but you can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367426/multi-dimensional-array-and-pointers-in-c/6226628#6226628.

Comment: @TonyK Both Nawaz and me *did* in fact answer this question correctly. Your way also works but I find it needlessly complicated, and at any rate inferior to using proper C++ classes.

Comment: @Konrad: I suspect that your real objection to my answer is that it is needlessly simple.

Comment: @TonyK Nothing of that sort. In fact, using vectors is vastly simpler. Now, what would your objection to *our* answers be?

Comment: @Konrad: You only have to look at Nawaz's answer to see that it's ten times more complicated than mine. Your answer is fine, except that it didn't answer the OP's question: "How do I do this?" "DO NOT DO THIS!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *image = new int[W][H]; -- is it wrong??
```

It will NOT compile. You should compile your code first, to know the answer of your question.

I think you want to do this:

```
//memory allocation
int **image = new int*[W];
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < W ; i++ )
   image[i] = new int[H];

//use it as
 for(size_t i = 0 ; i < W ; i++ )
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < H ; j++ )
          image[i][j] = some_value;
int value = image[20][30]; //get value at (20,30) assuming 20 < W and 30 < H

//memory deallocation
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < W ; i++ )
   delete [] image[i];
delete [] image;
```

But then why do all these when you've `std::vector`? You could use it which will do all these nasty thing itself. Here is how you should be using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > image(W, std::vector<int>(H));
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < W ; i++ )
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j < H ; j++ )
          image[i][j] = some_value;
int value = image[20][30]; //get value at (20,30) assuming 20 < W and 30 < H
```

Comment: How can I declare a multi dimensional array??

Comment: Heh, I just wanted to blame you for not trying to compiler yourself. :P At that time, the `NOT` was not there.

Comment: +1 for asking the questioner to compile.

Comment: @Xeo: Hehe.. I had edited that within 3 seconds.. but you're faster than me :D

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a question about C++:

**Do not use C-style arrays or pointers** (neither for 1D nor 2D arrays). Use the C++ data types, such as `vector`:

```
vector<int> image(W * H); // 1D array

vector<vector<int> > image(W, vector<int>(H)); // “2D” nested array.
```

This requires the [`vector` standard header](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Answer (score 2):

```
int** image = new int*[H];
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++)
    image[i] = new int[W];
```

Answer (score -2):

I use something like

```
int ** image....
```