# c++: new multi dimensional array of strings

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226490/c-multi-dimensional-array)

I'm trying to create a class that creates an arbitrary sized array of strings based on one of the objects constructor arguments.

Here, the code for the object constructor I'm trying so far:

```
commandSpec::commandSpec(int numberOfCommands)
{
    std::string * commands = new std::string[3][numberOfCommands];
}
```

I get an error: 'numberOfCommands cannot appear in a constant expression', could someone show me the correct way to specify an array in an object that i dont know the size of until execution.

Thanks, j

Comment: And God (or was it Stroustrup ?) created the `vector`.

Comment: so is it bad form to add an array on the heap like that (if i fix the syntax)? I thought that as the size wont change after its created i wouldnt need the featres that a vector would give me, i just need a simple array thats size will be defined at runtime but will still be fixed when it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be implemented as a structure and a vector, like this:

```
struct command {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
    std::string third;
};

commandSpec::commandSpec(int numberOfCommands)
{
    std::vector<command> commands(numberOfCommands);
}
```

Of course, you should choose appropriate names for the members of `command`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are allowed only when allocating on heap.

You need to allocate the array in 2 steps - first allocate array with length `3` (from pointers) and then loop through the 3 elements and allocate new string for each.

I'd recommend you to use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order of the dimensions...

```
commandSpec::commandSpec(int numberOfCommands)
{
    std::string (*commands)[3] = new std::string[numberOfCommands][3];
}
```

However, I highly recommend you consider using vectors instead.

Comment: This doesn't work. It just isn't how C++ handles arrays.

Comment: @Beta: sorry, forgot the lhs array part; this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a std::vector instead, makes life easier:

```
commandSpec::commandSpec(int numberOfCommands)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> mystrings(numberOfCommands);
}
```

Comment: I think you have the dimensions in the wrong order. It should be 3 first, then numberOfCommands.