# C++ Multi dimensional array indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367426/multi-dimensional-array-and-pointers-in-c). However, I could not get the meaning for the following declaration.

Lets say I declare this:

```
Declaration 1:    int jimmy [HEIGHT][WIDTH];

   Accessing 1:   jimmy[n][m]

Declaration 2: int jimmy [HEIGHT * WIDTH];


 Accessing 2:  jimmy[n*WIDTH+m]
```

Declaration 1 and accessing 1, and Declaration 2 and accessing 2 are same [src](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

However, what is the meaning **jimmy[n,m]**?  I wrote the code it gives me address. Couldnt get any useful info. Can some one say what does it mean?

Comment: See also: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54142/995714), [What is the proper use of the comma operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17902992/995714), [When to Overload the Comma Operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5602112/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ has a comma operator which evaluates the thing on the left, discards the return value, and then evaluates to the thing on the right.

You could write (see http://ideone.com/hpQxWI)

```
int i = (1, 2, 3, 4);
std::cout << i;
```

and you would print out 4.

So

```
jimmy[n,m]
```

means

```
jimmy[m]
```